# How to get required text from the selected html content

Tags: python-3.x

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html_content = """<div class='ui very padded vertical segment'>
<div class='ui basic clearing segment' style='margin: 0; padding: 1em 0'>
<h4 class='ui header'>
Description
</h4>
<p>Please bring the failure blade to cabin.</p>
</div>
<div class='column'>
<h4 class='ui header'>
Owner Information
</h4>
<div class='ui list'>
<div class='item'>
<i class='grey user icon'></i>
<div class='content'>No Owner Specified</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>"""

work_order_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"html.parser")
find_description = work_order_soup.find(re.compile("^h[1-6]$"), text=re.compile("Description", re.IGNORECASE))

parent_div_description = find_description.find_parent("div")
print(parent_div_description.text)
```

Without finding the p tag I need to get the text from the parent div. I need to actually get rid of Description from the text. I have already find the description using find_description.
Required solution: Please bring the failure blade to cabin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<h*>` tag from the parent and get the text:

```py
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = """<div class='ui very padded vertical segment'>
<div class='ui basic clearing segment' style='margin: 0; padding: 1em 0'>
<h4 class='ui header'>
Description
</h4>
<p>Please bring the failure blade to cabin.</p>
</div>
<div class='column'>
<h4 class='ui header'>
Owner Information
</h4>
<div class='ui list'>
<div class='item'>
<i class='grey user icon'></i>
<div class='content'>No Owner Specified</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>"""

work_order_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
find_description = work_order_soup.find(
    re.compile("^h[1-6]$"), string=re.compile("Description", re.IGNORECASE)
)

parent = find_description.parent
find_description.extract()

print(parent.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Please bring the failure blade to cabin.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the way you extract and process the text from the parent_div_description. Since you've already located the parent div of the "Description" header, you can iterate through its children and selectively get the text from the relevant tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import re

html_content = """<div class='ui very padded vertical segment'>
<div class='ui basic clearing segment' style='margin: 0; padding: 1em 0'>
<h4 class='ui header'>
Description
</h4>
<p>Please bring the failure blade to cabin.</p>
</div>
<div class='column'>
<h4 class='ui header'>
Owner Information
</h4>
<div class='ui list'>
<div class='item'>
<i class='grey user icon'></i>
<div class='content'>No Owner Specified</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>"""

work_order_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
find_description = work_order_soup.find(re.compile("^h[1-6]$"), text=re.compile("Description", re.IGNORECASE))

parent_div_description = find_description.find_parent("div")

# Initialize an empty list to hold the text parts
text_parts = []

# Iterate through the children of the parent div
for child in parent_div_description.children:
    # Check if the child is a NavigableString and not empty
    if isinstance(child, NavigableString) and child.strip():
        text_parts.append(child.strip())
    # Check if the child is a tag but not the 'h4' tag with 'Description'
    elif child.name != 'h4' or (child.name == 'h4' and 'Description' not in child.text):
        text_parts.append(child.get_text(strip=True))

# Join the parts to form the final text
final_text = ' '.join(text_parts).strip()

print(final_text)
```